# How to change the cursor color C# console

Tags: c#-4.0, colors, console.log

I wanted to know if there any method out there that let you change the cursor color on a C# console App?

The default color for the cursor is gray.

[image]

A picture for demonstration.

Comment: It is the opposite of the background with the high-intensity bit turned off.  If you want it to be, say, yellow then use Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; Console.Clear();  A bit like using a sledgehammer to turn a screw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Like @Hans Passant suggested. The only way to do it is changing the Background color and then clearing the console.